# Special characters are not being read from a JSONP file correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have some JSONP files which have data like: `"ActiveLabel":"Site Survey Exact-Built™"` (notice the `™` char).

When I read the data from the file, by creating a script tag and using that to evaluate the JSONP file, then I get `�` where `™` should be.

I tried setting `charset="UTF-8"` on the script tags I generate to load the JSONP, but that isn't helping.

Any idea what I can do to correct this?

Comment: What `Content-Type` are you specifying on the HTTP response containing the JSONP?

Comment: I'm working on a single page application that will run on the `file:` protocol, so I'm using whatever the default values are that I cannot change.

Comment: hehe since I'm usng the `file:` protocol there are no HTTP headers =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `charset="Cp1252"` on the `<script>` elements that I was creating, and that worked. Got to get the charset right..

Comment: see [follow-up question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788305/special-characters-are-not-being-read-from-a-jsonp-file-correctly-in-ie8/4788360#4788360), in short use `charset="windows-1252"` when you want IE to work too.