# Special characters are not being read from a JSONP file correctly in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Same problem as [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742771/special-characters-are-not-being-read-from-a-jsonp-file-correctly) I asked but specifically for IE, since the answer I gave works in everything except IE. So this question is specifically for IE:

How can I set the charset to be used when reading a javascript file via a `script` element in IE?

I have a JSON file with a `™` character in it and when I include the file on to my HTML page with `<script charset="Cp1252" ...` (which works in every other browser) on IE, then I get the following character `�`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer requires that the value for `charset` is `Windows-1252`.

- [Windows-1252 (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752010%28VS.85%29.aspx)

This should be a more universally compatible value for the `charset` attribute - [HTML5 defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.charset-def) that the value should be a case-insensitive match of a name or alias in the [IANA Character Sets Registry](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsCharacterSets):

```
Name: windows-1252
MIBenum: 2252
Source: Microsoft  (http://www.iana.org/assignments/charset-reg/windows-1252) 
Alias: None
```

I know that Firefox supports this value too, as a synonym for CP1252, the specification suggests that other browsers should too.